# Documentation for old versions of Clojure java.jdbc?

Tags: jdbc, clojure

The [Using java.jdbc] documentation is very sparse and the [clojure.java.jdbc - JDBC-based SQL Interface 0.3.0 API documentation](http://clojure.github.io/java.jdbc/) is only for the latest version. [I imagine the title of that last link will change when a new version is released.]

I'm using version 0.2.3 – where can I find the API documentation for that vesion? Or where can I find the info that likely would have been in the API docs for that version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the docs in the [proper tagged branch in GitHub](https://github.com/clojure/java.jdbc/blob/java.jdbc-0.2.3/doc/clojure/java/jdbc/UsingSQL.md).

[Table dropping](https://github.com/clojure/java.jdbc/blob/java.jdbc-0.2.3/doc/clojure/java/jdbc/UsingDDL.md) in your example.

If those docs are not enough you can always refer to the [properly tagged](https://github.com/clojure/java.jdbc/blob/java.jdbc-0.2.3/src/main/clojure/clojure/java/jdbc.clj#L522) source code of that version.

Comment: I was looking for the 'API documentation', mainly to check the signature of functions.

Comment: I accepted this answer because, in my experience, it's often necessary to refer to the source. It's not convenient, but it's not necessarily a bad thing overall either.

Answer (score 1):

I can use the following commands from a Leiningen REPL to find what seems to be the same info as shown in the API docs to which I linked in my question.

List all keys (sorted) of "[... a map of the public intern mappings for the namespace.](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/ns-publics)", i.e. all of the symbols defined and publicly accessible in the namespace:

```
my-app=>(sort (keys (ns-publics 'clojure.java.jdbc)))
(as-identifier as-key as-keyword as-named-identifier as-named-keyword ...
```

Show the documentation for a particular symbol:

```
my-app=>(doc clojure.java.jdbc/drop-table)
-------------------------
clojure.java.jdbc/drop-table
([name])
  Drops a table on the open database connection given its name, a string
  or keyword
nil
```